# Injecting ApplicationDbContext to use in Aspnet Core Identity in multilayer project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I have a multilayer architectured c# project, I don't want to add Reference to My DAL layer from Presentation, So I need to inject ApplicationDbContext for use in Identity at runtime, for this approach I writed an extention method in Business layer for this. (Presentation Layer has reference to Business Layer) and added this method in startup.cs as below:

```
public static IdentityBuilder AddDbContext(this IdentityBuilder builder, IServiceCollection services, string connStr)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext>(_ => new ApplicationDbContext(connStr));

        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
               .AddDefaultTokenProviders();            

        return builder;
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {           
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddDbContext(services, Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    }
```

But when I ran my Application, it crashes when trying to run.

the error page is as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Problem,
Actually the problem is not because of DI, It's because I did not add using directive for my Domian Project into _ViewImports.